# Are there any Rest frameworks supports Reliability Messaging?

Tags: rest

We have a system that use Rest service as communication infrastructure. Recently, We deploy it on a poor network with High latency,Low bandwidth and High packet loss rate, I want to improve it's reliability.I found that there is a dispute on the need for a reliable Rest service.
The articles about this topic I found is below:

[Nobody Needs Reliable Messaging](https://www.infoq.com/articles/no-reliable-messaging)

[RELIABLE MESSAGING WITH REST](https://www.jetpen.com/blog/2015/08/23/reliable-messaging-with-rest/)

I agree with the latter one, because I have met the same problems mentioned in this article. Are there any opensource Rest frameworks supports Reliability Messaging? Are there any comparison articles about these frameworks?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the http://restmq.com/ ? As it uses Redis under the hood, you can configure it to persist the state as well.